# Proper way to wait for multiple threads to complete before exiting program in c++ 11

Tags: multithreading, c++11

The code sample below would effectively allow one 1 thread at a time to perform. Keeping references to the threads and then calling 'Thread.join' sometime later has the same effect. How to let these threads run in such a way  with the program waiting for the threads to continue independently and in parallel, and then exiting? It would appears to me that some other Kernel object signaling mechanism must be used. (In short using 'join' to tie the main thread to a secondary thread doesn't let the other threads run concurrently?)

```
int main() {
    while (cin) {
        getline(cin, input_line);
        if (input_line.length()>0)
        {
            thread t = thread(SomeLengthyCheck, input_line);
            t.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "In short using 'join' to tie the main thread to a secondary thread doesn't let the other threads run concurrently?" -- that assumption is simply wrong. Just start multiple threads that only sleep for a second. Then, join all those threads and watch how much time the overall program takes.

Comment: @Ulrich I was referring to my above code fragment, since the effect of calling the 'thread.join' in the while loop would not even launch the other threads.. Using a join after all threads are created would allow the other threads to continue on until completion (as described below). Also I understand the spec states the threads should continue even after the main thread exits, but I'm not comfortable with that approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally use a thread array, then wait for all of them on a for loop.

You don't care for the order as, eventually, all of them should finish.

On your case, you'll need a thread stack/queue as you don't know how many threads you'll have to wait for.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::string input_line;
    while (getline(std::cin, input_line)) {
        if (input_line.length()>0) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(SomeLengthyCheck, input_line));
        }
    }
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();    
}
```

---

EDIT: Exception safe version suggested by @o11c

```
class vthreads : std::vector<std::thread> {
    ~vthreads() { for (auto& th : *this ) th.join(); }
};

int main() {
    vthreads threads;
    std::string input_line;
    while (getline(std::cin, input_line)) {
        if (input_line.length()>0) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(SomeLengthyCheck, input_line));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exception safe though. Better to put the call to `.join` in a destructor that will be called automatically.

Comment: @o11c Good catch, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert with linux but i think threads are attached to `main`'s process so while any threads operating asynchronously of the main thread, simply `return`-ing in main will have the o.s. close the process and all children threads attached.

Else I believe the threads will end when the calling function finishes after the enclosing `{}`

You could signal to the main process when this happens with a global variable.

Also I think you are confused about the join. Join forces an asynchronous thread (function) to essentially run synchronously by stopping the calling thread until the thread which to be joined, finishes.

Comment: A global variable should work because the threads of a parent process share the same memory resources.

Comment: The behaviour is not defined by Linux but rather the C++ standard. That standard also says that a `std::thread` must be either detached or joined before its destructor call. Simply leaving the scope where the `std::thread` was created does neither of the two, causing a call to `abort()`, I think.